# Passing form values to controller variables

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, paypal

Working on a semi-complex donation system with multiple payment gateways and need to grab some extra vaules in my PayPal form to store in the Database. Having trouble passing the values from the Main Form to my PayPal Controller and store in my DB.

Here is a small breakdown of how it is working.

- 1. Main Forms optional fields before it hits payment gateways

     ```
     <input type="text" id="people" name="people" value="">

     <select onchange="tripbehalf(this);" id="tripbehalf">
         <option selected="true" value="">Optional Info</option>
         <option value="x">This is for X.</option>
         <option value="y">This is for Y</option>
         <option value="z">Both Options</option>
     </select>
     ```
- 2. Script to grab values & send to PayPal Form

     ```
     <script>
     function updateExtraFields(fieldName, selector) {
         $('form input[name="' + fieldName + '"]').val($(selector).val());
     }

     $('#tripbehalf').on('change', function() {
         updateExtraFields('d_type', '#tripbehalf');
     });

     $('#people').on('change', function() {
         updateExtraFields('people', '#people');
     });

     </script>
     ```
- 3. PayPal Form gets values and sends to PayPal Controller

     ```
     <form action="{{ route('xxx.store') }}" method="post" target="_top">
         <input type="hidden" name="amount" value=""/>
         <input type="hidden" name="d_type" value=""/>
         <input type="hidden" name="people" value=""/>
             <button type="submit">PayPal</button>
     </form>
     ```
- 4. Pass above values to PayPal controller to use in storing data

     ```
     public function store(Request $request) {
     $item = (new Item)
         ->setName('Poverty Resolutions Donation')
         ->setCurrency('USD')
         ->setQuantity(1)
         ->setPrice($request->amount);
         $d_type=$request->d_type;
         $people=$request->people;

         dd($request->all()); // <--THIS RETURNS THE D_TYPE & PEOPLE CORRECT VALUE

     return $this->paypal->setItems([$item])->charge($request->amount);
     }
     ```
- 4.5 How I get from 4 to 5

  ```
  public function success(Request $request) {
      if (empty($request->PayerID) || empty($request->token)) {
          // TODO: Properly redirect with an error message
          dd('No payer ID or no token');
  }

  $apiContext = $this->paypal->apiContext();

  $execution = (new PaymentExecution)->setPayerId($request->PayerID);
  $payment = Payment::get($request->paymentId, $apiContext)->execute($execution, $apiContext);

  if ($payment->getState() !== 'approved') {
      // TODO: Properly redirect with an error message
      dd('Payment failed');
  }

  $payerInfo = $payment->getPayer()->getPayerInfo();

  $paypalTransaction = PayPalTransaction::create([
      'payer_id' => $payerInfo->getPayerId(),
      'payment_id' => $payment->getId(),
  ]);
  ```
- 5. Need to pass the D_TYPE & PEOPLE Values here and store in the database.

     ```
     $paypalTransaction->transactions()->create([
     'user_id' => auth()->id(),
     'customer_email' => $payerInfo->getEmail(),
     'amount' => $payment->getTransactions()[0]->getAmount()->getTotal() * 100,
     'recurring' => false,
     'gift_trans_fee' => $request->gift_trans_fee === 'true',
     'd_type' => $request->d_type,
     'people' => $request->people,
     ]);
     ```

Need help to figure out how to get the values of `d_type` and `people` into Part #5

On Part #5 have tried `'d_type' => $d_type` & `'people' => $people` but get error: `Undefined variable: d_type` Even though I'm grabbing the value in Part #4

Comment: where you have #5 code ? inside store function ?

Comment: how do you get to #5 from #4?

Comment: @Wreigh I have updated my question with more info from the controller